# Which programming language do I need in order to allow users to create content like Wattpad does with it's user?

Tags: javascript, php, ruby, wattpad

For example, Wattpad allows it's users to create"chapter" for their content, each user can create unlimited "chapter's" and it performs similar to reading a book online when published.

Comment: The programming language isn't the question. You can implement the functionality in any language. It's just a matter of segmenting, parsing, and displaying the data. However, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. My recommendation is to find a language you're comfortable with, and try it yourself. If you get stuck with a specific error, feel free to post a new question.

Comment: this is only possible in PHP :), just kidding see above ^

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll look more into it then.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  It will help you craft better questions, which (hopefully) will help produce better answers. As it stands, your question is off-topic because it's "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".   Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Check out their tech stack on their [Stack Overflow Company Page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/wattpad).

It lists JavaScript, PHP, and SQL as languages they use.

You could build a site like Wattpad using only JavaScript. The important piece to how users can publish content, and can publish content as a number of chapters, is how their data is structured and stored in the database.

Comment: I'd argue that looking at another company's tech stack is the worst way to pick your own tech stack. It's better to pick one that you're comfortable with, so you're able to use your own knowledge to solve issues, rather than trying to hobble along, following in the footsteps of someone else without necessarily knowing anything about it.

Comment: Eric Phillips cool, I didn't know a site like stack overflow exist. I will look into that and thanks for confirming the language they use. Brandon I don't plan on copying their code but with so many programming languages out there I didn't know if I should focus on php, ruby on phython. I plan on learning the basic of all them later on, but I just wanted a sense a direction towards my goal.